# NextJs creating user document in mongodb after google sign in

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

i want to create a user document after i sign in with google in my nextjs application. I can sign in but it's not creating the document after it. This is my function

```
  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      await signIn("google");
      await addUser();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Erro");
    }
  };
```

The addUser function is

```
  const addUser = async () => {
    if (status === "authenticated") {
      const user = {
        name: session.user.name,
        email: session.user.email,
        avatar: session.user.image,
      };

      try {
        await fetch("/api/new_user", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(user),
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Not logged in");
    }
  };
```

This is how i'm creating the new document in my `new_user.ts` file in the `api` folder

```
export default async function handleNewUser(req:NextApiRequest, res:NextApiResponse){
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("bookdb");
    const coll: Collection = db.collection("users");

    const user = req.body

    console.log(user)
    
    try {
        await coll.insertOne(user)
        res.status(200).json({response:'Success'})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error:'Erro'})
```

To make sure it was working, i triggered manually the addUser function after signing in and it worked.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: The signIn part is ok, what i'm trying to achieve is creating a user document on mongodb right after signing in

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that `redirect: false` only works for the `credentials` and `email` providers. It won't work for `google` provider, ignore my previous comment.

Comment: It's fine, i got it. I used a useEffect that triggers when the status change, so when it's 'authenticaded' it will call the function to create the new document

Comment: As an alternative, you may be able to use the [`signIn` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#sign-in-callback) to execute some logic on the server whenever a user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

this is my snippet for google auth sign in with mongodb and nextjs using typescript and prisma.

```
signIn: async ({user, account}) => {

            if (account?.provider === 'google') {
                const googleAuthData = {
                    name: user.name,
                    email: user.email,
                    image: user.image,
                    authProvider: 'google',
                    password: ''
                }
                const exist = await prisma.user.findFirst({
                    where: {email: user.email},
                });
                if (exist) {
                    const result = await prisma.user.update({
                        where: {email: user.email},
                        data: {image: user.image},
                    });
                } else {
                    const result = await prisma.user.create({
                        data: googleAuthData,
                    });

                }
            }
            return true;

        },
```